# How to permit <br> with text?

Tags: html, ruby, line-breaks, html-safe

How can we give the user the ability to break-lines here?

`<%= f.text_area :name, rows: 4, class: 'form-control', id: "gold-standard", placeholder: 'Enter Value' %>`

Ideally only `<br>` would work out of the html elements, but worst case how can we permit all html elements, like `<b>`, `<u>`, etc?

For the latter case I tried using `:name.html_safe` or `text_area.html_safe` but those gave me errors. Thanks!

Comment: Don't ever trust user input. Do not give them the ability to write html in your application. What kind of name uses four lines of input? Can you show me a sample of input you are expecting.

Comment: @MenelikTucker `:name` isn't the best description. It's so users can basically write any content like a quote, fact, story that reflects their values.   I want them though to be able to choose how to format their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just about `<br>` I would use the [`simple_format` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) method.

If you user enters "Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break." as a name, then you can output that line break as a `<br>` like this:

```
<%= simple_format(@valuation.name) %>
# => "<p>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</p>"
```

If you need more complex things like `<strong>`, `<ul>`, `<hx>` I would consider allowing users to use a markup language like Markdown (e.g. with the [Kramdown gem](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html))

Comment: I'm confused by your example. How does it relate to my example? Thanks Spickerman!

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com The example came directly from the documentation. I hope now it is more clear.

Comment: I tried this: `<%= f.simple_format :name, rows: 4, class: 'form-control', id: "gold-standard", placeholder: 'Enter Value' %>`, f being @valuation, but I get an error.

Comment: I read the documentation before I posted this question, but it didn't make sense to me and I was getting errors so I thought it wouldn't work.

Comment: You do not have to change the `text_area` for the input. The user can already just add line breaks into that `text_area. You have to change the output, so that the line breaks get replaced by `<br>`. Use the code above instead of `<%= @valuation .name %>` on the show page.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! That's why i was so confused lol